# ActionContextCleanUp is deprecated Struts2 Archetype

Tags: struts2, maven-archetype

Just started using Struts2. I thought it would be a good idea to to use the struts2 archetype, but it appears that is very outdated. When I run my project, I keep getting this warning:

```
ActionContextCleanUp <<< is deprecated! Please use the new filters!
```

Here is my current web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Test</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Welcome file lists -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

What do I change to get rid of the warning?

Comment: Which version of archetype are you using?

Comment: Not sure which version, here's the command I used: mvn archetype:generate -B -DgroupId=tutorial -DartifactId=tutorial  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts  -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter. I didn't include -DarchetypeVersion=<version> because I read that I didn't need it to get the latest version.

Comment: Please for a JIRA ticket. You get rid of the warning by removing the filter is warning you about. IIRC there's a SiteMesh show case you could look at for reference, although I don't know if it suffers from the same problem or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it figured out. After looking at [this example](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/sitemesh-plugin.html) web.xml file for the sitemesh plugin, I ended up with a working web.xml file. Here's what it looks like for anyone else having this problem:

```
<display-name>Test</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts-execute</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Listeners -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Welcome file lists -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Now that warning is gone.

Comment: I don't think you need the StrutsPrepareAndExecute filter when you have already done them individually first. I don't use it and neither does the example you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete filter action2-cleanup.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>action2-cleanup</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ActionContextCleanUp</filter-class>
</filter>
```